# Getting the full category hierarchy string for a friendly-url from a php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, friendly-url

I'm trying to get the full string for appending on a friendly url from a php multidimensional array of **undefined depth**. Similar to what Wordpress does. The result would be like `parent/son/grandson`. Here is an example of the array I'd have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [slug] => animals
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 29
                            [slug] => insects
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 32
                                            [slug] => grasshoppers
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 28
                            [slug] => mammals
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 30
                                            [slug] => dogs
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 31
                                            [slug] => horses
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [slug] => minerals
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33
                            [slug] => salt
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I would like to call a function like:

```
$full_slug = getFullSlug('dogs', $array);
```

And the content of **$full_slug** would be:

```
"animals/mammals/dogs"
```

After some research i found examples for similar cases using **array_unshift** on **recursive methods**, but I could not come with something working for this particular case on my own. Any help with that little **getFullSlug()** function would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do using recursion:

```
function getFullSlug($key, $array) {
        foreach($array as $node) {
            if($key == $node['slug']) { //Found it on this node
                return $node['slug'];
            }
            else //Search depth first
            {
                if (isset($node['children']) && is_array($node['children']) && !empty($node['children']) ) {
                    $subSlug = getFullSlug($key, $node['children']);
                    if(!empty($subSlug)) //If it was found
                    {
                        return $node['slug'].'/'.$subSlug;
                    }
                    else //Look at the next sibling
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                } else { // This is a leaf, and it wasn't found
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return ''; //Failed to find it.
    }
```

Of course, this could be added to a class as well. If you do that then you need to update the getFullSlug call to $this->getFullSlug(....).

Here is the slugs array I tested it with which should be exactly like you mentioned:

```
$slugs = array(
    array(
        'id' => 26,
        'slug' => 'animals',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 29,
                'slug' => 'insects',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 32,
                        'slug' => 'grasshoppers'
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 28,
                'slug' => 'mammals',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 30,
                        'slug' => 'dogs'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 31,
                        'slug' => 'horses'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 27,
        'slug' => 'minerals',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 33,
                'slug' => 'salt'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Finally, here is some code using the function:

```
echo getFullSlug('animals', $slugs).'<br>';
echo getFullSlug('insects', $slugs).'<br>';
echo getFullSlug('grasshoppers', $slugs).'<br>';
echo getFullSlug('mammals', $slugs).'<br>';
echo getFullSlug('dogs', $slugs).'<br>';
echo getFullSlug('horses', $slugs).'<br>';
echo getFullSlug('minerals', $slugs).'<br>';
echo getFullSlug('salt', $slugs).'<br>';
```

And the corresponding output, as expected:

```
animals 
animals/insects 
animals/insects/grasshoppers 
animals/mammals
animals/mammals/dogs 
animals/mammals/horses 
minerals 
minerals/salt
```

Hope this helps!

**P.S. To check if a slug exists you can use empty().**

For the example above,

```
$url = getFullSlug('platypus', $slugs);

if(empty($url))
    echo "Slug doesn't exist";
else
    echo "New url: $url";
```

would print "Slug doesn't exist" if platypus doesn't exist in the $slugs multidimensional array, and it would print something like "New url: animals/mammals/platypus" if it did exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the accurate and didatic answer. It helped me a lot. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to up vote the answers that were helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
public function getFullSlug($key, $array) {
    foreach($array as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
        if (is_array($arrayValue)) {
            return $arrayKey . '/' . $this->getFullSlug($key, $arrayValue);
        } else if ($arrayValue === $key) {
            return $arrayValue;
        }
        throw InvalidArguementException("full slug could not be built for $key", 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick FYI, I am on my iPhone so I haven't actually tested that 

Comment: In fact, I don't even need to test it to see that it will not work if you are not looking down the first available path, but it's something to start with that you can build upon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)